# Rails plugin for showing lists/index pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datagrid

I'm looking for a Rails plugin that facilitates showing lists of objects. Ideally I'd like to pass an ActiveRecord query and get a table that shows a result of this query. The table should be sortable, paginated and searchable (using some kind of filters).

I've already found two that might be ok. The first is [DataGrid](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid). It looks fine, but it uses `will-paginate` and as I adopted `kaminari` in the project, I'm not sure if such mixing would be a good idea. 
[FancyGrid](https://github.com/giniedp/fancygrid) looks tempting, but it seems to be not maintained and so I'm not sure, if it's good idea to use it.

Do you know anything more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a railscasts that may be relevant. See [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables)

Comment: Finally I decided to use datatables, thanks! Do you know about which wrapping gem should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Fancygrid is currently in the proess of being refactored. Please be patient, there will definitely be a new release.

A new version of [FancyGrid](https://github.com/giniedp/fancygrid) has been just released.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all related plugins here:
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Table_Builders

So there are several other plugins:

- Tabletastic
- TableForCollection
- Tableasy